# Dataform source declaration on Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, dataform, google-bigquery-dataform

I'm using the dataform on the GCP console. I've created a `definitions/sources/declaration.js` file where I call the built-in js function `declare()` to reference tables on other BigQuery projects. Is there a way of defining an alias to a table declaration that could be used as reference on the `ref` function in the .sqlx files (instead of hard coding the table name)? Ex:

```
// definitions/sources/declaration.js
declare({
   database: <table_database>,
   schema:   <table_schema>,
   name:     <table_name>,
   alias:    <declaration_alias_name>
})

// definitions/tables_creation/final_table01.sqlx

select
   *
from ${ref("<declaration_alias_name>")}
```

This would be useful if a `table_name` changed, because it would be necessary to change only the declaration file and not all the .sqlx that use that reference.

A way extract and save the `table_name` of a declaration to a variable would also work.